# slide content based on button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set up a content area where there are 3 button choices. Based upon the button the user chooses, different content will slide into place. Depending upon which section they are under (which button was selected) the button will be a different color - white instead of orange.

Here is a link to the general idea of what I am trying to accomplish. 
Your help is appreciated.

http://jsbin.com/epibab/2/edit

Comment: Where is the question???

Comment: My question is, why is it not working properly/smoothly? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/epibab/14/edit)*

HTML: removed all relevant `ID`s :

```
<div id="hopperContentNav_ctr">
    <ul class="hopperTabs">
        <li><a href="#" class="active tab-1" >RECORD, WATCH, STORE&mdash;<br />IN ANY ROOM!</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tab-2" >COMMERCIAL-FREE TV<br />IN PRIMETIME!</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tab-3" >MOVIE MADNESS&mdash;<br />ANYTIME, ANYWHERE!</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And instead ID I added classes `page`:

```
<div class="page">
    <p class="wholeHomeHead">Whole-Home-DVR</p>
            ........
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.page:gt(0)').hide(); // hide all pages but first one using :gt() selector

    $('.hopperTabs li').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisInd = $(this).index();
        $('.page').stop().fadeTo(300,0,function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('.page').eq(thisInd).stop().fadeTo(600,1);
        });             
    });
});
```

Sorry for not using the hide() and show() with slide... I'll leave it to you. I had some issues and not used to use this jQuery UI.

Comment: That did not seem to work properly for me.

Comment: @maddev strange, the demo works really properly.

Comment: Found out I only needed to implement an absolute positioning to the content divs. Thanks for the help!